# ReactJS: Increment counter keeps refreshing component

Tags: reactjs, counter, increment

So recently I started a project for fun to mess around with NextJS.

I ran into a problem regarding my count state:

```
//Core
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

//Style
import styles from './form.module.scss';

export default function Form({ placeholder }) {
  const [count, setCounter] = useState(0);

  return (
    <form>
      <input
        type='text'
        placeholder={placeholder}
        className={styles.error}
      ></input>
      <button onClick={() => setCounter(count + 1)}>{count}</button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

This keeps refreshing my count state everytime I click the increment button. What is the correct way to do a increment on click, without rerendering the comoponent?

I found examples like these online:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-counter-demo-kevxp?file=/src/index.js:460-465

How come my counter keeps resetting, and theirs is not?

Comment: What is the problem with that code? Since `count` is a state, when you change it, React will re-render it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are inside a `form`.

Use `preventDefault` first in order for the form not to be submitted everytime.

```
  <button
    onClick={(e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      setCounter(count + 1);
    }}
  >
    {count}
  </button>
```

See it in action [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-chaum-tw8rt?)

Comment: Adding a `type="button"` to the button works aswell. 
When you wrap a button into a form the default type is `submit` it means it try to submit your form to a specfic url once you click on the button.

Answer (score 2):

You can also set the button's type to "button" to prevent form submission

```
<button type="button" onClick={() => setCounter(count + 1)}>{count}</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

With a `useRef` you can keep the same data across re-renders

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";

export const Form = () => {
  const counterEl = useRef(0);
  const [count, setCount] = useState(counterEl.current);

  const increment = () => {
    counterEl.current = counterEl.current + 1;
    setCount(counterEl.current);
    console.log(counterEl);
  };

  return (
    <>
      Count: <span>{count}</span>
      <button onClick={increment}>+</button>
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because you wrap your button in form
by default when you press button in form submit trigger
and then whole page render so state reset